# How to perform cluster analysis on categorial data in R

Tags: r, clustering, pca, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I have survey data with 1000 respondents, each one has awnsered 20 questions related to different product features of a car. Each question could be awnsered as "good", "indifferent" or "bad". Consequently, I have for each of the 20 questions one categorial variable with three different expressions. I have provided a smaller sample dataframe to illustrate the data. Id being the respondent id and a,b,c illustrations of the 20 product questions.

```
a <- sample(c(1:3),100,replace=T)
b <- sample(c(1:3),100,replace=T)
c <- sample(c(1:3),100,replace=T)
id <- c(1:100)
df <-data.frame(id,a,b,c)
```

I now want to **identify clusters within the questions, whether certain type of features of the car should be grouped together**, thus showing certain segments among my respondents.

I tried using R's k-means algorithm but found out that this one is only for numerical data.

**Could anybody provide an approach to identify the segments?**

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a "market basket" type problem.  Sorry I don't I have a good reference to  provide. Maybe start here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256012/item-item-collaborative-filtering-vs-market-basket-analysis